How to Automate service now tickets using airflow for dag failure
I want to create service now ticket whenever there is dag failure in airflow and i want to automate this by using airflow and python api call
I'm not getting how to do API call and set in airflow connection
if you found any reference share it

You can write your custom on_failure_callback and in that function send a REST request to ServiceNow api  using say the python requests.post method:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/latest/rest/c_TableAPI#table-POST
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/washingtondc-api-reference/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/change-management-api.html

import requests


def open_snow_tkt(context):
    snow_url = 'your_snow_url/api/sn_chg_rest/v1/change/normal'
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept':'application/json'
    }
    snow_ticket = { 
        'description': 'details',
        'short_description': 'brief summary',
        'category' : 'AirflowDAGFailure'
    }
    response = requests.post(snow_url, data=json.dumps(snow_ticket), verify=False, headers=headers)


with DAG(
    # omitting other lines, set the failure callback
    on_failure_callback=open_snow_tkt,
):

